# EXCEL - Extract and replace word with alphabet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of names in excel of a class. It contains a column "Full name". The Fullname has 3 parts, viz:
1. First Name (FN)
2. Middle Name (MN)
3. Surname (SN)

eg: 
Aashish Ajit   Handa
(FN)     (MN) (SN)

I want to be able to change the same to
Aashish A. Handa
i.e., The middle name should be searched, and the first alphabet should replace the (MN).
The middle name is different character length.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Despite someone posting an answer, please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: @CharlieRB - I didnt do anything. coz i have never used excel so extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the names that match your pattern and run this short macro:

```
Sub NameFixer()
    Dim s As String, r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, " ")
        ary(1) = Left(ary(1), 1)
        r.Value = Join(ary, " ")
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

*(Because there is no error-checking, avoid **Selecting** cells that do not match your pattern)*

Answer (score 1):

A non-macro way of doing this same problem is to break down the 3 names as a formula and combine it. I normally would use the name manager for this but will also show the extended formula that does not use the name manage. (All of these examples will use the a1 cell as having a name that is Name (space) Name (space) Name format
Step 1 get the First name.

1. Fname=+LEFT(Sheet1!A1,FIND(" ",Sheet1!A1))
   This searches for the first space and returns everything to the left
2. Lname=+RIGHT(Sheet1!A1,LEN(Sheet1!A1)-FIND(" ",Sheet1!A1,1+LEN(Fname)))
   This returns the last name. We need both the first and last name to bracket the answer. This assumes there are only 2 spaces, and searches for the 2nd space by doing a find that starts after the first space.
3. Mname=MID(Sheet1!A1,1+LEN(Fname),LEN(Sheet1!A1)-LEN(Fname)-LEN(Lname))
   This returns the full middle name by using the Fname and Lname to bracket.

to put It all together

4. =(Fname&LEFT(MName,1)&". " &Lname)
   The ". " after the left(mname,1)  could be " " if did not want the period.

In a single line without using names is

5. =LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))&LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,1))&". "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1+FIND(" ",A1)))

Problems with this approach,

- Sensitive to data structure issues, put an iferror in front with a ,"Name Format error" such as
- =+IFERROR(Fname&LEFT(MName,1)&" " &Lname,"Name format error")

Also may need to do a substitute to replace double spaces with single spaces.

- Aname=substitute(a1,"  "," ")

Which may be needed depending on how good your data source is at being exactly following format.

Comment: ..............Nice Approach ! ................